# Hilberts Theorem (norm group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The theorem says the following:  The map $N$ is a group homomorphisim from the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}^{x}[i]$ to the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}^{x}$ and has kernel $\lbrace \dfrac{z}{\sigma(z)} | z \in \mathbb{Q}^{x}[i] \rbrace $

I understand the proof but there is one part of the proof I do not understand and that is showing that given a element in the kernel of $N$ we show that it must be in the form of $\dfrac{z}{\sigma(z)}$. Is there some way to show this?

$z=x+iy$

$\sigma(z) = x-iy$

$n(z)=z \sigma(z)$

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of Hilbert's Theorem 90. Because you are just looking at this special case, there is a very fun way to see this.

If you plot points in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ in the complex plane, saying that a point is in the kernel of the norm map means precisely that it is a point with rational coordinates on the unit circle.  There is a venerable old result describing exactly such points -- the rational parameterization of the unit circle.  It says that all such points have coordinates of the form

$$\left( \frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2+n^2}, \frac{2mn}{m^2+n^2} \right)$$

for some integers $m$ and $n$.  There are many easily googlable sources for this, for instance:

http://math.rice.edu/~evanmb/math499spring10/vigrenotes3.pdf

Believing this, you want to show that such a point must have the form $\tfrac{z}{\sigma(z)}$ for some $z$.  If you try $z=m+in$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers giving the coordinates of your element of the kernel above, then

$$
\frac{z}{\sigma(z)} = \frac{m+in}{m-in} = \frac{(m+in)^2}{(m-in)(m+in)} = \frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2+n^2} + i \frac{2mn}{m^2+n^2}
$$

This point has the same coordinates as your point in the kernel, so you've found your $z$.

P.S. Noam Elkies dicusses this here

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/hilbert.pdf

but takes the point of view of establishing the above parameterization of the unit circle from Hilbert's Theorem.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but you are using a theorem that requires hilberts theorem to justify it. Could we apply some sort of induction to this like assume n(z) is true..... then n(z+1) is true

Comment: The rational parameterization does not need Hilbert's theorem to justify it. Just some geometry. See the link I provided or many other sources.

Comment: in another proof I am reading they said the following: Let $z \in Ker(N)$ then $z(\sigma(z+1))=z\sigma(z)+z=v(z)+z=1+z$ Thus $z=\dfrac{z+1}{\sigma(z+1)}$ and he finishes the proof like that. What I want to know is where does he come up with that conjecture in how he chose the element $z \sigma(z+1)$?

Comment: It is related to the proof of Lemma 2 on p.90 here:

http://math.arizona.edu/~cais/scans/Cassels-Frohlich-Algebraic_Number_Theory.pdf

Birch says "the proof is by direct construction, which is providentially possible". The construction you read comes from specializing a standard proof of Hilbert's Theorem 90 in the general setting of cyclic extensions to the one you are considering.